# I am trying to test elements in two arrays, and the first element in the second array is not getting tested

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

```js
function six(sll) {
  let list = [];
  for (i = 0; i < sll.length; i++) {
    console.log(sll[i]);
    //these are my if statements to test elements
    if (sll[i].slice(0, 1) !== "e" && sll[i].length < 6) {
      list.push(sll[i]);
    } else if (sll[i].length > 6 && sll[i].slice(0, 1) === "e") {
      list.push(sll[i]);
    }
  }
  return list;
}
//this is my first array
let sxt = ["taco", "eggs", "excellent", "exponent", "artistic", "cat", "eat"];
console.log(six(sxt));
//this is my second array and the word eating is not being tested
let xxx = ["eating", "proper", "key", "earth"];
console.log(six(xxx));
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not being tested? Its length is 6. You only push words whose length is less than 6 or greater than 6, but not exactly equal to 6.

Comment: That is because `eating` has exactly a length of `6`. When comparing, you need to use either `>=6` or `<=6` somewhere, otherwise you will just not evaluate any strings that are precisely 6 chars long

Comment: Off-topic: no need for `.slice(0, 1)`, you can simply do `sll[i][0]`

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 letters in eating, and you're testing for things that are less than 6 letters. use the <= operator in your conditional.